# Correct use of EXIT_FAILURE in C program?

Tags: c

I'm writing a web app that needs to use several ansi C functions to crunch data. Another language, probably Java, will call the main C function to trigger the process. I want to return a value from the main C function for the Java script to evaluate success or not. I expect C's use of `exit()` was created for this reason.

As I go about programming C, there are several times I run into situations that I could evaluate to examine whether or not the program is running correctly. For example, if I have a variable that can only equal "equation 1", "equation 2" or "equation 3", and then I use an

```
if(var==equation1) { 
  /*statements*/
} 
else if(var==equation2) {
  /*statements*/
} 
else if(var==equation3) {
  /*statements*/
}
```

statements to check which of the three possibilities it is, I could add an `else { }` to the end, whose contents I expect will never execute in a normally running program, to catch unexpected problems. I want to place an `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` in this last `else { }` statement. If I understand it correctly, this will cause the program to terminate, and return a non-zero value to the Java calling program for it to detect. Is that correct?

Can I sprinkle this `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` throughout various functions, not just `main()`, for the same reason?

Some questions about the mechanics of setting this up -- Is the main function simply setup as: `int main(void);` assuming no input arguments for simplicity? That is, the int is needed to return the integer value called by the macro `EXIT_FAILURE`... is that right?

If the `main()` function called another function, and that function contained an `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` statement, does that other function need to specifically include a return in its prototype, e.g. `int function_one(void);` where the int is needed to return the `EXIT_FAILURE` status, or is `the EXIT_FAILURE` macro self-sufficient in this regard, so that if the function_one wants to return, say, a character, then its prototype can be `char function_one(void);` and no worry about returning anything for `EXIT_FAILURE` in its prototype?

Comment: What C functions do you need that aren't available in Java? Your life will be easier without splitting your workload this way. Or do you need to use some very task-specific library?

Comment: I need to use fast-fourier transform (see www.fftw.org, only available in C and Fortran), and also speed of execution of several functions is critical. My impression, from what I hear, is C is generally faster than Java.

Comment: Numbercrunching is indeed a good reason for calling out to C. Googling around gave me the [Shared Scientific Toolbox library](http://carsomyr.github.com/Shared/) which, amongst other things, seems to include a reasonably recent binding to FFTW for Java. A binding would let you call FFTW functions directly from Java, but the heavy lifting would be done in C code.

Comment: Thanks for the link Inerdial. The owners would benefit if it appeared here: http://www.fftw.org/download.html under "Calling FFTW From Other Languages." The existing Java link there appears broken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The return type `int` of `main` is effectively the return value that the calling process sees. The general idea is that your `main` does this as any other function namely `return EXIT_FAILURE`. Whenever possible you should use this direct approach.

The function `exit` can be used to shortcut all this and to return to the caller from any other function than `main`. But the return value of a function that uses `exit` has nothing to do with the fact that it might to a preliminary exit through `exit`. So you don't have to change any prototype of your functions.

Your other assumptions seem to be correct, and your use of `exit` to terminate an invalid invocation looks valid to me.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can call `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` anywhere in your program.

Notice that `exit` is related to [atexit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit). See also [_Exit](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit) (which is rarely useful)
and [abort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/abort)

Comment: \_exit() is _very_ useful, especially after fork(), as it skips calling an exit handler you may have installed with on_exit().

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can call `exit` from anywhere to terminate the program. Feel free to use it anywhere you think that your program should not continue.

Also instead of using generic `EXIT_FAILURE`, you might want to devise your own error codes so that you can give a little more info to the caller than just "Something went wrong". and use that with `exit` (remember you can call it with any 8-bit value, not just `EXIT_FAILURE` or `EXIT_SUCCESS`). For instance, 0 might be success, 1 might be input read failure, 2 might be input formatting error, and so on.

Comment: You can exit with any int in the range 0..255.  Values outside that range are not preserved.

Comment: Other values than the predefined macros for `exit` are marked as implementation specific by the standard. There is no guarantee that these will reach the caller, I think. What @DietrichEpp reports is AFAIR specific to POSiX. I have no idea how other OS handle this.